# What is NetworkAccess.Local in Xamarin Essentials?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.essentials

I hope this is an appropriate question for this forum. I'm a total noob with mobile development and I've been asked to develop a mobile app that will grab a csv file from our company network. In Xamarin Essentials, if a mobile device has NetworkAccess.Local does that mean that the device is physically connected to a network via a, for example, USB cable? Is there a way to simulate that with an emulator or would I have to use a real device? I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: according to the docs, "Local – Local network access only.".  That generally means it is connected to a network, but does not have broader internet access

Comment: But connected physically, right, via a cable, not via WiFi or some other over-the-air method?

Comment: No, why would that matter?  Physical devices are rarely connected to the network via cable.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I said, my boss wants me to write a mobile app that will grab a csv file from our company network. If the device isn't connected via WiFi or Internet (in which case NetworkAccess would be Internet or WiFi), then how is it connected to the local network?

Comment: you are comparing two different properties, `NetworkAccess` (Internet, Local) and `ConnectionProfile` (Ehternet, WiFi, etc)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I apologize. But I still don't understand how a device can be on a local network yet not connected to the Internet, or via a cable. Unless it's via WiFi or Bluetooth? I'm just trying to get a handle on how this works and whether I can simulate this in an emulator or need to use a physical device.

Comment: You can connect to a WiFi access point that is only connected to a local network and has no external connectivity.  Or to a physical ethernet router that is connected to a local network but not the internet.  Regardless, I'm not sure why this is a blocker to what you are trying to do.  You can just attempt to make a connection to the server you need without checking connectivity first.  If it fails, then handle that failure.